# Entity Framework - select collections along-side one entity in its collection

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two entities in C#. One is `Box`. The other one is `Ball`.

A `Ball` must belongs to a `Box`. Which means that there is a `BoxId` on `Ball`.

```
public class Box
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Ball> Balls { get; set; }
}

public class Ball
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int BoxId { get; set; }
    public Box Box { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to get some boxes, with the lastest ball inserted in it because I need to know its color.

I have tried this way:

```cs
// Runs slow because there is too many balls.
var boxes = await Boxes
.Where(somecondition)
.Include(t => t.Balls)
.ToListAsync()

foreach (var box in boxes)
{
    // Get the color which I only need.
    box.Balls.OrderByDesending(t => t.CreationTime).First().Color;
}
```

But doing this will query all balls in the database. Now there are lots of balls(about 10,000,000) so it queries slow.

I only need the last inserted box. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with Select and fetch only last record for Balls like below.

Also when we use Select we can remove .Include because it won’t have any effect here.

```
var boxes = await Boxes
            .Where(somecondition)
            .Select(t => new Box(){
              Id = t.Id,
              Balls = t.Balls.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationTime)
                         .Take(1)
            })               
            .ToListAsync()
```

Comment: I wonder if it will cause a null pointer exception for you are calling `t.Balls.Something` without include `t.Balls`

Comment: No it won’t. Select will take care of it. Give it a try.